# Whmcs auto auth

Tags: whmcs

We are currently using [auto auth](http://docs.whmcs.com/AutoAuth) and we have the method below to log in the user automatically using there email, the problem is when the email has a [plus sign](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) it will not login automatically.

```
/**
 * @param $email Clients Email Address to Login
 * @param string $goto is a url endpoint where you want to redirect the user
 */
public static function autoLoginUser( $email, $goto = 'index.php?m=dashboard' )
{
    global $CONFIG;

    /**
     * Define WHMCS url and AuthKey from confguration.php
     */
    $whmcsurl = $CONFIG['SystemURL'] . "/dologin.php";
    $autoauthkey = "Our auth key is here"; //$autoauthkey from configuration.php

    $timestamp = time(); //Get current timestamp
    $hash = sha1($email . $timestamp . $autoauthkey); //Generate Hash

    /**
     * Generate AutoAuth URL & Redirect
     */
    $url = $whmcsurl . "?email=$email&timestamp=$timestamp&hash=$hash&goto=" . urlencode($goto);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Does anyone have tried this before? Having a normal email address works perfectly but on email that contains plus sign it won't log the user automatically.

Comment: not sure but try replace + in email with %2B to escape url as WHMCS creates slug from email and it could be issue with encoder.

Comment: HI @LukaSvalina I have tried that one but it didnot work. I will post what works on our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it was not documented in whmcs but the work around we manage to have is encode the email like the following code

```
/**
 * @param $email Clients Email Address to Login
 * @param string $goto is a url endpoint where you want to redirect the user
 */
public static function autoLoginUser( $email, $goto = 'index.php?m=dashboard' )
{
    global $CONFIG;

    /**
     * Define WHMCS url and AuthKey from confguration.php
     */
    $whmcsurl = $CONFIG['SystemURL'] . "/dologin.php";
    $autoauthkey = "Our auth key is here"; //$autoauthkey from configuration.php

    $timestamp = time(); //Get current timestamp
    $hash = sha1($email . $timestamp . $autoauthkey); //Generate Hash
    $email = 
    /**
     * Generate AutoAuth URL & Redirect
     */
    $url = $whmcsurl . "?email=".urlencode($email)."&timestamp=$timestamp&hash=$hash&goto=" . urlencode($goto);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```